# uiview touch move get the anchorpoint on uiview

Tags: ios

I have a view which, when I click on it, will move left and right. I only get the point center of the view. How can I get the uiview on the anchorpoint because where ever i click on the view it will move.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 

{
    NSLog(@"touchesMoved called"); 

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    CGPoint touchpoint=[touch locationInView:self.view];  

    if ([touch view]==secondView)
    {
      secondView.center=touchpoint;
      [self animateFirstPoint:[touch view]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right you're searching for the anchorpoint of the UIView.

First import QuartzCore:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Now you can use the anchorpoint of your view:

```
secondView.layer.anchorPoint = touchpoint;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember you have to specify anchor point like CGPointMake(x,y), where x and y are more or equal to 0 or less or equal to 1;
For example:

```
CGPoint selectionAnchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.15, 0.2);
```